# Adverial that clause

Tags: sentence-construction

> I go to work every day that my earnings may be helpful to caring for my ill mother.

Is it acceptable?

What I want to describe is that 'I go to work every day for it that my earnings may be helpful to caring for my ill mother'.

Comment: Yes, it's acceptable. "That my earnings may be helpful to caring for my ill mother" is a declarative content clause functioning as a purpose adjunct. It gives the purpose of your going to work every day.

Comment: @BillJ Is it so old-fashioned, though?

Comment: @BillJ I would characterize it as 'literary' rather than 'formal'; you don't often encounter it in academic or bureaucratic dialects.

Comment: Yes, pretty archaic really, and very formal.

Comment: Then why in the world advise learners to use it?

Comment: @JeffMorrow I don't see anyone "advising learners to use it". Try making a constructive comment instead of a negative sarcastic one.

Comment: @BillJ "It is acceptable" will almost certainly be construed to mean to go ahead with a usage that is "pretty archaic and very formal." The question does not appear to relate to Early Modern English. It appears to relate to what will be idiomatic, modern speech. A great many current speakers of American English will find that "acceptable" usage at least odd and perhaps incomprehensible.

Comment: @JeffMorrow odd?  A bit.  Incomprehensible?  Only to idiots.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is marginally acceptable, but it is likely to be misunderstood. Bare *that* with the sense *so that* has been rare since the 17th century, and even then it was set off with a comma (reflecting 'comma intonation' in speech) to indicate that it modified the entire preceding clause.

> I go to work every day, that my earnings ...

Without the comma the *that* in your construction will be parsed as a relativizer introducing a clause modifying *day*. (That is, it distinguishes days on which your earnings help you care for your mother from other days on which your earnings will not help you care for her—which doesn't make a lot of sense.)

You would do better to say

> I go to work every day ***so that*** ... *or*
>   I go to work every day ***in order that*** ...

A couple of minor points: 1) Today we rarely use *ill* as an attributive adjective, before the noun it modifies. In that position it tends to bear the now obsolete sense of "bad". Instead, we use *sick* or *ailing*. 2) We don't say *helpful **to** VERBing* but *helpful **in** VERBing*.

> ... helpful in caring for my ailing mother.

Comment: After re-reading your answer, I see that I misinterpreted what you wrote.  Sorry.

Comment: However, even though "my ill mother" is a bit archaic, it's still ok.  In fact, I think its nice.

Comment: Would you agree that the fact that the clause is 'ungoverned' is a cause of confusion when it comes to parsing?

Comment: @BillJ More or less--I think its position immediately following the NP creates the 'garden path'. This can be overcome in writing/speech with a comma/comma intonation: with that 'disjunct' the *that* cannot be a relativizer, since *that* generally does not introduce nonrestrictive relatives. Consequently we take the clause to be a clausal adjunct.

Answer (score 1):

> > I go to work every day that my earnings may be helpful to caring for my ill mother.
>
> Is it acceptable?

Almost.  I'd write it as, "I go to work every day, that my earnings may be helpful <s>to</s> **in** caring for my ill mother."

Note the added comma after "day" and "in" instead of "to".